# Error in compiling/installing RealTime Kernel on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: kernel, compiling

I need to install a RealTime Kernel for working with ROS2 and I have followed this [guide](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Building-Realtime-rt_preempt-kernel-for-ROS-2.html) very carefully. But I get always the same error:

```bsh
make[2]: *** [debian/rules:6: build] Errore 2
dpkg-buildpackage: Errore: debian/rules build subprocess returned exit status 2
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.package:77: deb-pkg] Errore 2
make: *** [Makefile:1464: deb-pkg] Errore 2
```

For instance the passages that I have used on the terminal are the following:

- Create a new folder and enter in the folder: `mkdir kernel && cd kernel`
- Download the kernel and the patch: `wget https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/linux-5.4.78.tar.gz` and `wget http://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/5.4/older/patch-5.4.78-rt44.patch.gz`
- Unpack and Unzip the two archives: `tar -xzf linux-5.4.78.tar.gz` and `gunzip patch-5.4.78-rt44.patch.gz`
- Enter in the kernel folder: `cd linux-5.4.78`
- Patching the file: `patch -p1 < ../patch-5.4.78-rt44.patch`
- Using the old configure, in this case I had 2 configs so I have used: `cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config` for my case `$(uname -r)` is `5.4.0-70-generic`
- Added in the settings of Updates the source code as source and installed other dependencies as written in the guide
- Enable configurations: `yes '' | make oldconfig`
- Enable the different settings in the menu after: `make menuconfig`
- The error happen during the making with: `make -j` nproc `deb-pkg`

How can I solve?

Part of the output (warnings and errors are here):

```bsh
scripts/kconfig/conf  --syncconfig Kconfig
make clean
  CLEAN   arch/x86/purgatory
  CLEAN   arch/x86/realmode/rm
  CLEAN   arch/x86/kernel/cpu
  CLEAN   arch/x86/kernel
  CLEAN   arch/x86/entry/vdso
  CLEAN   kernel/debug/kdb
  CLEAN   kernel
  CLEAN   usr
  CLEAN   fs/unicode
  CLEAN   arch/x86/tools
sh ./scripts/package/mkdebian
  TAR     linux-5.4.78-rt44.tar.gz
origversion=$(dpkg-parsechangelog -SVersion |sed 's/-[^-]*$//');\
    mv linux-5.4.78-rt44.tar.gz ../linux-5.4.78-rt44_${origversion}.orig.tar.gz
dpkg-buildpackage -r"fakeroot -u" -a$(cat debian/arch)  -i.git -us -uc
dpkg-buildpackage: Informazioni: Pacchetto sorgente linux-5.4.78-rt44
dpkg-buildpackage: Informazioni: Versione sorgente 5.4.78-rt44-1
dpkg-buildpackage: Informazioni: Distribuzione sorgente focal
dpkg-buildpackage: Informazioni: Sorgente modificata da kappa95 <kappa95@kappa95-asus-laptop-x505za>
dpkg-buildpackage: Informazioni: Architettura host amd64
 dpkg-source -i.git --before-build .
 fakeroot -u debian/rules clean
rm -rf debian/*tmp debian/files
make clean
 dpkg-source -i.git -b .
dpkg-source: Informazioni: using source format '1.0'
dpkg-source: Avviso: source directory 'linux-5.4.78' is not <sourcepackage>-<upstreamversion> 'linux-5.4.78-rt44-5.4.78-rt44'
dpkg-source: Avviso: .orig directory name linux-5.4.78.orig is not <package>-<upstreamversion> (wanted linux-5.4.78-rt44-5.4.78-rt44.orig)
dpkg-source: Informazioni: building linux-5.4.78-rt44 using existing linux-5.4.78-rt44_5.4.78-rt44.orig.tar.gz
dpkg-source: Informazioni: building linux-5.4.78-rt44 in linux-5.4.78-rt44_5.4.78-rt44-1.diff.gz
dpkg-source: Avviso: ignoring deletion of file .scmversion
dpkg-source: Avviso: the diff modifies the following upstream files: 
 .clang-format
 .cocciconfig
 .config.old
 .get_maintainer.ignore
 .mailmap
 CREDITS
 MAINTAINERS
 README
dpkg-source: Informazioni: use the '3.0 (quilt)' format to have separate and documented changes to upstream files, see dpkg-source(1)
dpkg-source: Informazioni: building linux-5.4.78-rt44 in linux-5.4.78-rt44_5.4.78-rt44-1.dsc
dpkg-source: Avviso: missing information for output field Standards-Version
 debian/rules build
make KERNELRELEASE=5.4.78-rt44 ARCH=x86     KBUILD_BUILD_VERSION=1 -f ./Makefile
make[4]: ***  Nessuna regola per generare l'obiettivo «debian/canonical-certs.pem», necessario per «certs/x509_certificate_list».  Arresto.
make[4]: *** Attesa per i processi non terminati....
make[3]: *** [Makefile:1729: certs] Errore 2
make[3]: *** Attesa per i processi non terminati....
arch/x86/hyperv/hv_apic.c: In function ‘__send_ipi_one’:
arch/x86/hyperv/hv_apic.c:201:1: warning: the frame size of 1032 bytes is larger than 1024 bytes [-Wframe-larger-than=]
  201 | }
      | ^
arch/x86/hyperv/hv_apic.c: In function ‘hv_send_ipi_mask_allbutself’:
arch/x86/hyperv/hv_apic.c:226:1: warning: the frame size of 1032 bytes is larger than 1024 bytes [-Wframe-larger-than=]
  226 | }
      | ^
arch/x86/kernel/cpu/mce/core.o: warning: objtool: mce_panic()+0x123: unreachable instruction
kernel/exit.o: warning: objtool: __x64_sys_exit_group()+0x18: unreachable instruction
fs/btrfs/extent_io.o: warning: objtool: __set_extent_bit.cold()+0xc: unreachable instruction
fs/btrfs/relocation.o: warning: objtool: update_backref_node.cold()+0xb: unreachable instruction
arch/x86/xen/enlighten_pv.o: warning: objtool: xen_cpuid()+0x20: can't find jump dest instruction at .text+0x97
arch/x86/kernel/smpboot.o: warning: objtool: native_play_dead()+0x131: unreachable instruction
arch/x86/kernel/kvm.c: In function ‘kvm_send_ipi_mask_allbutself’:
arch/x86/kernel/kvm.c:503:1: warning: the frame size of 1032 bytes is larger than 1024 bytes [-Wframe-larger-than=]
  503 | }
      | ^
  
fs/jffs2/xattr.c: In function ‘jffs2_build_xattr_subsystem’:
fs/jffs2/xattr.c:887:1: warning: the frame size of 1128 bytes is larger than 1024 bytes [-Wframe-larger-than=]
  887 | }
      | ^

make[2]: *** [debian/rules:6: build] Errore 2
dpkg-buildpackage: Errore: debian/rules build subprocess returned exit status 2
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.package:77: deb-pkg] Errore 2
make: *** [Makefile:1464: deb-pkg] Errore 2
```

Answer (score 2):

I followed this guide https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/294116/419660

`sudo gedit .config`

Add a `#` in front of the lines `CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEY` and `CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_KEY` to comment them out. Select all defaults when prompted after running `make -j numproc deb-pkg`

I also needed to turn off secure boot in the bios https://github.com/jakeday/linux-surface/issues/575

Answer (score 2):

I had this error several times when installing a real-time kernel, and the issue seems to be with compiling to a debian package. Every tutorial I followed that did not compile to a debian package has worked. Here are 2 simple tutorials that I have tried and have worked (you also need to install flex and bison for these):
https://hmenn.github.io/pages/UbuntuRT_patch.html
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51709420

On a side note, are you using a Dell computer? Every person I've found so far that's had this issue has been using a Dell computer.

Comment: Can confirm that I'm using a Dell computer and ran to this issue.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like the same error that I got and the solution was removing this feature of the Kernel.

**SYSTEM_BLACKLIST_KEYRING = N**

Answer (score 2):

You can change your config file .config

**CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS="debian/canonical-certs.pem"**

to

**CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS=""**

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
scripts/config --set-str CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS=""
scripts/config --set-str CONFIG_SYSTEM_REVOCATION_KEYS=""
```