# Installing PREEMPT_RT kernel on ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS (focal)

Tags: 20.04, kernel, realtime

I am trying to install a real kernel that I need for  an application (controlling a UR robot) and I followed the [UR driver tutorial](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver/blob/master/ur_robot_driver/doc/real_time.md) on git hub on how to install it.

First I ran the command:

```
$ uname -r
5.15.0-69-generic
```

Infact I run -a to show it all.

```
$ uname -a
Linux Hamza 5.15.0-69-generic #76~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 20 15:54:19 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I also have a Intel® Core™ i5.

I now want to install a version close to my version  which is version 5.14.2. Here are all the commands I do:

```
mkdir ~/kernel
cd ~/kernel
wget https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/5.14/patch-5.14.2-rt21.patch.xz
wget https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/5.14/patch-5.14.2-rt21.patch.sign
wget https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/linux-5.14.2.tar.xz
wget https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/linux-5.14.2.tar.sign
xz -dk patch-5.14.2-rt21.patch.xz
xz -d linux-5.14.2.tar.xz
```

Then there is the verification step which I skipped.

```
tar xf linux-5.14.2.tar
cd linux-5.14.2
xzcat ../patch-5.14.2-rt21.patch.xz | patch -p1
make oldconfig
```

Here I press 4 for `Fully Preemptible Kernel (RT) (PREEMPT_RT_FULL) (NEW)` and for the rest I press enter.

I in the end build the kernel:

```
make -j `getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN` deb-pkg
```

The error I get:

```
make[2]: *** [debian/rules:7: build-arch] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules binary subprocess returned exit status 2
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.package:77: deb-pkg] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:1569: deb-pkg] Error 2
```

And here are the different warnings I get during the compilation.

```
dpkg-source: warning: source directory 'linux-5.14.2' is not <sourcepackage>-<upstreamversion> 'linux-upstream-5.14.2-rt21'
dpkg-source: warning: .orig directory name linux-5.14.2.orig is not <package>-<upstreamversion> (wanted linux-upstream-5.14.2-rt21.orig)
dpkg-source: warning: ignoring deletion of file .scmversion
dpkg-source: warning: the diff modifies the following upstream files: 
dpkg-source: warning: missing information for output field Standards-Version
arch/x86/hyperv/hv_apic.c:240:1: warning: the frame size of 1032 bytes is larger than 1024 bytes [-Wframe-larger-than=]
fs/jffs2/xattr.c:887:1: warning: the frame size of 1144 bytes is larger than 1024 bytes [-Wframe-larger-than=]887 | }
```

I really hope someone can see where I went wrong or has a better method for installing because other solutions such as these did not work; [One](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1327749/error-in-compiling-installing-realtime-kernel-on-ubuntu-20-04-2-lts),[two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51669724/install-rt-linux-patch-for-ubuntu/51709420#51709420) and [this very recent one but no answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1466603/how-do-i-install-custom-real-time-linux-kernel-headers)

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** It would seem to me that the issue has more to do with the procedure that you're following, as my first observation is that the kernel you downloaded (5.14) is [no longer maintained according to the Linux Foundation site](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/realtime/preempt_rt_versions) referenced in [the Git project procedure that you're following](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver/blob/master/ur_robot_driver/doc/real_time.md). You may want to work directly with the project owner.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the following worked for me (Ubuntu 20 and kernel 5.15.79):

1. Edit `.config` file, comment out `CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTF`, and remove values from `CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_KEY`, `CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS`, `CONFIG_SYSTEM_REVOCATION_KEYS`
2. If compilation fails again, comment out `CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_FORCE` and `CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_ALL` in the `.config` file.

The parameters to edit I got from these manuals:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51669724/install-rt-linux-patch-for-ubuntu
- https://superuser.com/questions/1214116/no-openssl-sign-file-signing-key-pem-leads-to-error-while-loading-kernel-modules