# Unable to install real time kernel in ubuntu 20.04 after following 2 guides and different forum answers

Tags: 20.04, kernel, realtime

I' have been trying to install a real time kernel for my ubuntu 20.04, but after 2 days reading othe user issues and following guides, I always end in the same error when compiling the kernell. I would hihgly appreciate some help please, cause I'm very frustrated so far.

I have followed this guide, which is the guide for the robot I'm working on now:

https://open-dynamic-robot-initiative.github.io/robot_interfaces/doc/real_time.html

And this other guide from a user who was able to install it.

[Install RT kernell in 20.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1327749/error-in-compiling-installing-realtime-kernel-on-ubuntu-20-04-2-lts)

Starting from a clean install of 20.04, first I have update the kernel to the same version of the real time(for example, 6.3.3).  Then I have followed every step of those guides but I wasn't able to install it, my terminal shows this if I use `make -j8 deb-pkg`:

> error: creating source package requires git repository make[1](https://open-dynamic-robot-initiative.github.io/robot_interfaces/doc/real_time.html): ***
> [scripts/Makefile.package:40: check-git] Error 1 make[1](https://open-dynamic-robot-initiative.github.io/robot_interfaces/doc/real_time.html): *** Waiting
> for unfinished jobs.... warning: Not a git repository. Use --no-index
> to compare two paths outside a working tree usage: git diff --no-index
> []

and this if I use `make -j8 bindeb-pkg`:

> make[4]: *** [Makefile:2025: .] Error 2 make[3]: *** [Makefile:357:
> __build_one_by_one] Error 2 make[2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1327749/error-in-compiling-installing-realtime-kernel-on-ubuntu-20-04-2-lts): *** [debian/rules:8: build-arch] Error 2 dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules binary subprocess
> returned exit status 2 make[1](https://open-dynamic-robot-initiative.github.io/robot_interfaces/doc/real_time.html): *** [scripts/Makefile.package:114:
> bindeb-pkg] Error 2 make: *** [Makefile:1656: bindeb-pkg] Error 2

what I'm doing wrong? I configured the .config files as guide says but is not working